# How can I set priority of my new tab in sale order view Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created new tab for order view, but it will display at first . How can I set priority for display at last

[image]

I have used below code for add new tab

```
<referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">*****_****</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">******\*****\*****\****\****\****\****</argument>
        </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: - Its Solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution :)

1. replace `addTab` with `addTabAfter` in action method
2. add new argument in action tab

   `<argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>`

Answer (score 3):

To avoid custom tab opening by default, please add `sequence` in your `module.xml`

```
 <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I add the "addTabAfter" instead "addTab", and it is works, but it is selected by default, even isn't first tab

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
   <action method="addTabAfter">
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">modulename</argument>
     <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">VENTOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom</argument>
     <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I found the solution for sales order tab default in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212538/how-can-i-add-a-tab-in-sales-order-but-not-be-selected-by-default/212729#212729