# How can I add a Tab in sales_order, but not be selected by default?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.2

I use the code below to add after order_info tab, but I want when I display the order details the active tab to be order_info.

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
  <action method="addTabAfter">
    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
    <argument name="block"xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom</argument>
    <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
  </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions!

It was in Controller Action on execute function was set

> $this->_translateInline->processResponseBody($html)

and after I removed, the order_info remain selected tab

Bellow it is my code for execute function

```
public function execute(){

    $this->_initOrder();
    $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
    // Yes, this is the same block class that we defined in sales_order_view.xml
    $html = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom')
        ->toHtml();
    // $this->_translateInline->processResponseBody($html);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    $resultRaw->setContents($html);
    return $resultRaw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your module loads after `Magento_Sales`

Add the following code into your `module.xml` for this:

```
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```